# Invalid user credentials Paypal Sandbox test account

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using latest `Paypal SDK` for iOS, trying to test login and payment transaction in sandbox environment. I have already created a business account in **Sandbox test accounts page**. So I have a user email, password and a signature. But I am unable to login using those credentials. I get following error in response:

```
PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: invalid_user - Incorrect username/password. Please try again. (401) | PayPal Debug-ID: c3dd83c83d43e | Details: (
        {
        "error_description" = "Invalid user credentials";
    }
).
```

I am unable to understand the reason for invalid credentials.  What credentials I must use in order to login sandbox account from iOS SDK? Or am I missing something in my code?

**Code**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //paypal setup
    // Set up payPalConfig
    _payPalConfig = [[PayPalConfiguration alloc] init];
    _payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = YES;
    _payPalConfig.languageOrLocale = @"en";
    _payPalConfig.merchantName = @"Merchant nmae";
    _payPalConfig.merchantPrivacyPolicyURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/privacy-full"];
    _payPalConfig.merchantUserAgreementURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/useragreement-full"];
    _payPalConfig.languageOrLocale = [NSLocale preferredLanguages][0];
    self.environment = PayPalEnvironmentSandbox;
    self.payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = NO;

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    // Preconnect to PayPal early
    [PayPalMobile preconnectWithEnvironment:self.environment];
}

- (IBAction)makePayment:(UIButton *)sender {
if([self.amount.text isEqualToString:@""])
{
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Please enter amount to proceed" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
    return;
}

    self.resultText = nil;

    PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
    payment.amount = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:self.amount.text];
    payment.currencyCode = @"GBP";
    payment.shortDescription = @"Payment for Web77";

    if (!payment.processable) {
        // This particular payment will always be processable. If, for
        // example, the amount was negative or the shortDescription was
        // empty, this payment wouldn't be processable, and you'd want
        // to handle that here.

        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Payment is unprocessable" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
        return;
    }

    PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithPayment:payment configuration:self.payPalConfig delegate:self];

    [self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}

#pragma mark PayPalPaymentDelegate methods

- (void)payPalPaymentViewController:(PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController didCompletePayment:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
    NSLog(@"PayPal Payment Success!");
    self.resultText = [completedPayment description];

    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Please enter amount to proceed" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];


    [self sendCompletedPaymentToServer:completedPayment]; // Payment was processed successfully; send to server for verification and fulfillment
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)payPalPaymentDidCancel:(PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController {
    NSLog(@"PayPal Payment Canceled");
    self.resultText = nil;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark Proof of payment validation

- (void)sendCompletedPaymentToServer:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
    // TODO: Send completedPayment.confirmation to server
    NSLog(@"Here is your proof of payment:\n\n%@\n\nSend this to your server for confirmation and fulfillment.", completedPayment.confirmation);
}
```

**Note:** I have already initialized `PayPalMobile` with paypal client ID for sandbox environment.

**Side Question:**
What should `merchantName` contain? Should it be same as mentioned on paypal site?

Comment: hey did u find solution to this?

Comment: any solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

@engr-anum does [this information](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK#sandbox) help?

> While testing your app, when logging in to PayPal in the SDK's UI you should use a personal Sandbox account email and password. I.e., not your Sandbox business credentials.
>
> You can create both business and personal Sandbox accounts on the [Sandbox accounts](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts) page.

Regarding `merchantName`: As you'll see in the header file's comments for this property, `merchantName` applies only when you are using a `PayPalFuturePaymentViewController`. It is not relevant for a `PayPalPaymentViewController`.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your response. I could not route to login screen right now, because I am getting an error message before showing.. `there was an error connecting to paypal servers`.

Comment: Moreover console shows this: `PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: pp_service_error_json_parse_error - System error. Please try again later. (500) | PayPal Debug-ID: 908535aa5fe13 | Details: (
        {
        "ns_error" = "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)\" (No value.) UserInfo=0xa9afb60 {NSDebugDescription=No value.}";
    }
).`

Comment: Also whenever I try to create a personal test account for sandbox, there is always some error encountered and it fails.. May be there is some issue on server..

Comment: After looking up the debug ID, are you sure that you've entered the correct clientID from the App you created to use the Mobile SDK?  The error I'm seeing suggests something to do with that.